# Issue with jQuery In WordPress - Issues Retrieving Table With Pre-filled Out HTML Data From Database

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-database

I am really struggling with this. I have changed this code a dozen times. Hit a wall. Hope you can help. Thanks.

Trying to get back a request for a pre-created table that has been filled out from the database and then once received put that HTML on the screen.

The jquery is working getting a 200 - but no data comes back with it. Trying to get back the whole table with data filled in. I know it's something easy I am missing, I just cannot see what it is right now.

Here is my jquery file:

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    $tableuser = $(this).val();

    $('.table-header').on('click',(function() {
        var data = {
                    'action': 'admin-user-populate',
                    'tableuser': $tableuser,



        };
        $.post(adminuserdataonly.ajax_call, data, function (response) {
        $('#admin-table').html(response);
        })
        }))






});
```

})(jQuery);

And here is the PHP ajax grabbed file.

function admin_only_table()
{

```
    $display_table = "<table>";
    $display_table .= "<tr>";
    $display_table .= "<th>User_ID</th>";
    $display_table .= "<th>First Name</th>";
    $display_table .= "<th>Last Name</th>";
    $display_table .= "<th>Email</th>";
    $display_table .= "<th>Subject</th>";
    $display_table .= "</tr>";


    if(current_user_can('edit_posts')){

        global $wpdb;

        $tablename = $wpdb->prefix."formuserinput";
        $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tablename");
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $display_table .= "<td>";
            $display_table .= "<td>$row->user_id</td>";
            $display_table .= "<td>$row->first_name</td>";
            $display_table .= "<td>$row->last_name</td>";
            $display_table .= "<td>$row->email</td>";
            $display_table .= "<td>$row->subject</td>";
            $display_table .= "</td>";

        }

        $display_table .= "</table>";          
        wp_send_json_success($display_table);

    }

    else{
        $result = 4;            
        wp_send_json_success($result);
    }
```

}

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: If you put console.log(response); you should see you're getting a JSON object back.  That won't just populate a table for you.  You need to extract the code returned from the object. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$('#admin-table').html(response);
```

With

```
$('#admin-table').html(response.data);
```

The wp_send_json_success() function returns an array() with two keys.  One is named "success" and one is named "data".  You want the data, since success should just be true, assuming it was successful.

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/

Comment: That worked! Thank you.  That was the key I was missing. Your awesome =). Thanks, Pendo.